# Getting undefined when importing svg as ReactComponent in create-react-app project

Tags: reactjs, svg, create-react-app

I'm getting following error when trying to load svg as ReactComponent.

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Icon`.

I'm using create-react-app with typescript option to create project.
If I'm understanding the document correctly, I should be able to import svgs as ReactComponent out of the box(since CRA2.0).
But weirdly, I'm getting undefined for the imported component.

> Adding Images, Fonts, and Files · Create React App
>   https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files#adding-svgs

Currently using following packages.

```
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.0.8",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.3",
```

My code is below.

Icon.tsx

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { ReactComponent as IconSvg } from './IconSvg.svg';

const Icon: React.FC<IconProps> = props => {
  console.log(IconSvg); // undefined
  return (<IconSvg />);
};

export default Icon;
```

custom.d.ts

```js
declare module '*.svg' {
  import React = require('react');
  export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "custom.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "node_scripts",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: `import * as IconSvg from './IconSvg.svg';` see if this resolves. There's no export in SVG file thus the error. OR this `import IconSvg from './IconSvg.svg';`

Comment: Hi mate... have you solved this? I’m having the same problem.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `custom.d.ts` file as SVG is a known type by create-react-app...

Comment: Are you sure path to `.svg` file is correct?

Comment: > Note: this feature is available with react-scripts@2.0.0 and higher, and react@16.3.0 and higher.

I created a new CRA project using Typescript templates to test it, and it worked fine!

Comment: I am using `react-scripts` 4.0.3 and `react` 17.0.2 and I still get this problem of not being able to `import { ReactComponent }`, despite Typescript saying that it is available.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: `import MySvg from "MySvg.svg"` then  `<img src={MySvg}/>`

To import an SVG: `import MySvg from "MySvg.svg"` which will save the path as a string inside `MySvg`.

To render it, use an img tag as in standard HTML, since `MySvg` is actually a path: `<img src={MySvg}/>`

The reason you get undefined is that you are destructuring a string.

Comment: Oh thank you! From numerous pages in the internet only this one worked for me for React + Typescript setup. But I don't understand why importing as ReactComponent doesn't work because it is the recommended way for React.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Styled components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components)

```
import Logo from 'assets/logo.svg';

const Image = styled.img<Props>`<some setting for standard width and height for logo here`>

const LogoWrapper = styled(Image)`
transition: all 0.25s linear;
&: hover {
    transform: scale(1.25);
}`;

<LogoWrapper height={140} src={Logo} alt="Some Logo" />
```

This one is working er

Answer (score 0):

Another example of how to do SVG's with Typescript:-

```
export interface ISVG {
    viewBox?: string;
    width?: string;
    height?: string;
    fill?: string;
    className?: string;
}

export const SVG = ({
    viewBox = '0 0 200 200',
    fill = '#FA4D56',
    width,
}: ISVG): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <svg viewBox={viewBox} width={width}>
            <path
                fill={fill}
                d="M41.9,-43.6C54,-39.8,63.3,-26.3,59.5,-15.3C55.8,-4.2,39,4.3,31.4,18.6C23.7,32.8,25.1,52.8,16,65.4C6.9,78,-12.7,83.2,-25.5,76C-38.4,68.8,-44.5,49,-44.5,33.3C-44.5,17.6,-38.4,6,-37.3,-7.8C-36.3,-21.5,-40.5,-37.4,-35.1,-42.3C-29.8,-47.2,-14.9,-41.3,0,-41.3C14.9,-41.3,29.8,-47.3,41.9,-43.6Z"
                transform="translate(100 100)"
            />
        </svg>
    );
};
```

You can also export the SVG as follows: -

```
export {SVG as Shape}; or w/e naming you choose to export it as.
```

Things such as margin or padding should be applied afterward, I would assume since you want them to be as generic as possible and be able to re-use them in different locations.

Answer (score 0):

if what you need is to import SVGs as a component in React I would recommend this tool https://react-svgr.com/playground/
else the simplest way to deal with SVGs in react is the one mentioned by the other answers above.

Answer (score -1):

use this way
this is an exaple find your svg and put it in this function

> your svg file

```
interface IProps {
  fill?: string;
}
export default (props: IProps) => (
  <svg
    style={{ marginTop: "13px" }}
    fill={props.fill || Primary}
    viewBox="0 0 424 424"
    width={15}
  >
    <path d="M35,89C15,89,0,74,0,54s15-36,35-36h353c20,0,36,16,36,36s-16,35-36,35H35z" />
    <path d="M388,176c20,0,36,16,36,36s-16,35-36,35H35c-20,0-35-15-35-35s15-36,35-36H388z" />
    <path d="M388,335c20,0,36,15,36,35s-16,36-36,36H35c-20,0-35-16-35-36s15-35,35-35H388z" />
  </svg>
);
```

where you want to use svg

```
import React from "react";
import Menu from "./assets/svg/menu";

 ...
 return (
   ...
   <Menu/> 
 )
```

Comment: This is also my resolution for the time being, but it's a "workaround" IMO.  The default use of `import` an asset should work if create-react-app is using `SVGR` under the hood.