# React Scripts Import Svg as ReactComponent fails with complete app bundle

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Our web app is a very manual "micro front end" with a [Build-time (lock-step release process)](https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html).  The child apps are built as npm package and the parent wrapper builds before exporting final app.

In the child app, we have a new feature needing assets from SVGs to be rendered.  So I followed the recommended [SVG guidelines from the docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs).

```
import { ReactComponent as UploadIcon } from '../../../pages/Dashboard/assets/icon.upload.svg';

...component logic here:
return (<>
        {other logic here...}
        <UploadIcon />
       </>);
```

Now we export this all (including assets) and in the parent app, the npm version is updated.

App fails when loading the page because the UploadIcon is `undefined`.

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Same error as issue:
[Getting undefined when importing svg as ReactComponent in create-react-app project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672964/getting-undefined-when-importing-svg-as-reactcomponent-in-create-react-app-proje)

However, this is the fully bundled app, not the child app using it directly.

What could it be?  As a work around I am converting the SVG to a JS file and returning it as a variable value.

Comment: Hey Phil. Did you get a resolution to this, other than your workaround? I have run into the same issue.